Async lambda expression not compiling
I have a lambda expression with a Select where a new ResourcesResponse.Resource object is created. The Resource object has a calculated Order field which calls an async repository method called GetResourceTypeOrder and everything looks as follows:
ResourcesResponse instantiation:
var tmp = new ResourcesResponse
{
    Cost = aux.Sum(s => s.Cost),
    Resources = aux
        .OrderBy(k => k.Order)
        .ThenBy(k => k.TypeId)
        .Select(async s => new ResourcesResponse.Resource
        {
            Id = ((ulong)s.Id).ToString(),
            Charge = s.Charge,
            Cost = s.Cost,
            CurrencyCode = s.CurrencyCode,
            ForecastCharge = s.ForecastCharge,
            ForecastCost = s.ForecastCost,
            ForecastUsedUnits = s.ForecastUsedUnits,
            ParentId = ((ulong?)s.ParentId).ToString(),
            Order = await _resourcesRepository.GetResourceTypeOrder(s.TypeId),
            Rate = s.Rate,
            TypeId = s.TypeId,
            UsedUnits = s.UsedUnits,
        })
        .ToArray(),
    Id = ((ulong)entry.Id).ToString(),
    Name = entry.Name,
    Description = entry.Description,
    OriginalId = entry.OriginalId,
    ResourceTypeId = entry.ResourceTypeId,
    ResourceType = await _resourcesRepository.GetResourceTypeName(entry.ResourceTypeId),
    Order = await _resourcesRepository.GetResourceTypeOrder(entry.ResourceTypeId),
    State = entry.State,
    Zone = entry.Zone,
    Charge = aux.Sum(s => s.Charge),
};

ResourceResponse:
public class ResourcesResponse
{
    public string Id { get; set; } = default!;
    public string Name { get; set; } = default!;
    public string? Description { get; set; } = default!;
    public string OriginalId { get; set; } = default!;
    public string ResourceType { get; set; } = default!;
    [JsonIgnore]
    public int? Order { get; set; } = default!;
    public ResourceTypeValues ResourceTypeId { get; set; }
    public string? CurrencyCode => Resources?.FirstOrDefault()?.CurrencyCode;
    public decimal? Charge { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }
    public decimal? ForecastCharge { get; set; }
    public decimal? ForecastCost { get; set; }
    public string Zone { get; set; } = default!;
    public string State { get; set; } = default!;
    public Resource[] Resources { get; set; } = default!;

    public sealed class Resource
    {
        [JsonIgnore]
        public string Id { get; set; } = default!;
        [JsonIgnore]
        public string? ParentId { get; set; } = default!;
        [JsonIgnore]
        public int? Order { get; set; } = default!;
        public string CurrencyCode { get; set; } = default!;
        public decimal Rate { get; set; }
        public long UsedUnits { get; set; }
        public decimal Cost { get; set; }
        public decimal? Charge { get; set; }
        public long? ForecastUsedUnits { get; set; }
        public decimal? ForecastCost { get; set; }
        public decimal? ForecastCharge { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; } = default!;
        public ResourceTypeValues TypeId { get; set; }
        public string? Unit { get; set; } = default!;
        public bool? Hourly { get; set; } = default!;
    }
}

ResourceTypeOrder:
public async Task<int?> GetResourceTypeOrder(ResourceTypeValues resourceTypeId)
{
    ICache.Operation<int?> myTableCacheImplementation = async delegate (string key)
    {
        var dic = await _repositoryResourceTypes.FindAll().ToDictionaryAsync(k => k.Id);
        return dic[resourceTypeId].Order;
    };

    return await _vdcCache.GetOrCreateAsync(ResourceTypeCacheKey.ResourceTypeOrder, myTableCacheImplementation, null);
}


My problem is I don't know where to put the missing await (or whatever is needed for the entire expression to be accepted by the compiler).
For the parent ResourceResponse there is also a calculated Order field, but as you can see that one is correct.
It is obvious that I could add a .Result to the end of GetResourceTypeOrder and remove the async operator, but that's not the idea of an async / await.

Order = _resourcesRepository.GetResourceTypeOrder(s.TypeId).GetAwaiter().GetResult()

@Simon No. We don't do that here.

@Simon, thanks for your reply, but if I do that I obviously lose the benefits of async / await.

@Diego I'd recommend to create a bulk query for Resources that returns a dictionary and then just lookup and assign here (sync with O(1)).

Thanks for your input @Fildor, I'll try that, but I'm afraid I'll face the same problem, because the issue is not retrieving one string element or a dictionary, but the way it is retrieved, that is through Redis cache, and the method to get the key is async. Edit: Tried, and I can confirm my assumptions, the same problem occur.

Yes. Exactly. So Retrieve all respective items in one async call, resulting in a Dictionary (or Lookup for that matter) beforehand  and then your select here isn't async any more.

Even if you could get this working, you have an N+1 situation here with the query itself making another 2 calls to a repo (note: that wouldn't work inside an EF query anyway)

Thanks for your input @DavidG. Anything to suggest?

I'll answer myself:
The way to handle this (taking @Fildor comment as a start point) was to refactor the GetResourceTypeOrder method so it returns the complete dictionary, instead of a particular element. Then I just have to retrieve the dictionary before the ResourcesResponse instance creation and get -and assign- the corresponding Order to "Order" field as resourceTypes[s.TypeId].Order:
var resourceTypes = await _resourcesRepository.GetResourceTypes();

var tmp = new ResourcesResponse
{
    Cost = aux.Sum(s => s.Cost),
    Resources = aux
        .OrderBy(k => k.Order)
        .ThenBy(k => k.TypeId)
        .Select(s => new ResourcesResponse.Resource
        {
            Id = ((ulong)s.Id).ToString(),
            Charge = s.Charge,
            Cost = s.Cost,
            CurrencyCode = s.CurrencyCode,
            ForecastCharge = s.ForecastCharge,
            ForecastCost = s.ForecastCost,
            ForecastUsedUnits = s.ForecastUsedUnits,
            ParentId = ((ulong?)s.ParentId).ToString(),
            Order = resourceTypes[s.TypeId].Order,
            Rate = s.Rate,
            TypeId = s.TypeId,
            UsedUnits = s.UsedUnits,
        }).ToArray(),
    Id = ((ulong)entry.Id).ToString(),
    Name = entry.Name,
    Description = entry.Description,
    OriginalId = entry.OriginalId,
    ResourceTypeId = entry.ResourceTypeId,
    ResourceType = await _resourcesRepository.GetResourceTypeName(entry.ResourceTypeId),
    Order = await _resourcesRepository.GetResourceTypeOrder(entry.ResourceTypeId),
    State = entry.State,
    Zone = entry.Zone,
    Charge = aux.Sum(s => s.Charge),
};

GetResourceTypes:
public async Task<IReadOnlyDictionary<ResourceTypeValues, ResourceTypes>> GetResourceTypes()
{
    ICache.Operation<IReadOnlyDictionary<ResourceTypeValues, ResourceTypes>> myTableCacheImplementation = async delegate (string key)
    {
        return await _repositoryResourceTypes.FindAll().ToDictionaryAsync(k => k.Id);
    };

    return await _vdcCache.GetOrCreateAsync(ResourceTypeCacheKey.ResourceTypeOrder, myTableCacheImplementation, null);
}

